# Rails RSpec not seeing new model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I added a new attribute to my Booking model through a migration.

```
class AddPickupTimeEndAndPickupDetailsToBookings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :bookings, :pickup_details, :string
  end
end
```

I am now adding validation code:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  [...]
  validates :pickup_details, length: { maximum: 150 }
```

and suddenly all my Booking model specs are failing with:

```
Failure/Error: create(:booking)
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `pickup_details' for #<Booking:0x0000006d043e28>
```

Either I messed things up awfully, either I'm missing something obvious...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you run migrations for the test environment?

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate
```

Comment: So I was missing something obvious. Thank you!

Comment: In my case I had done some rollbacks and re-migrations and did't reset my test database. thanks!